# Ant design table filter: How to limit to one selection in the filter

Tags: reactjs, antd, web-frontend

I would like to have max 1 filter active at the same time.
I'm using Ant design table.

For the example below, I'd like to be able to select Male or Female without both options at once.

[image]

The code is taken from the Ant design documentation:

```
  {
    title: 'Gender',
    dataIndex: 'gender',
    filters: [
      { text: 'Male', value: 'male' },
      { text: 'Female', value: 'female' },
    ],
    width: '20%',
  },
```

Is there any simple trick to limit the selection to a max of 1?

Comment: You can use the custom filter panel - [link](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-custom-filter-panel). radio buttons can be used inside the panel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set [filterMultiple](https://ant.design/components/table/#Column) to false

```
 {
    title: 'Gender',
    dataIndex: 'gender',
    filters: [
      { text: 'Male', value: 'male' },
      { text: 'Female', value: 'female' },
    ],
    filterMultiple: false,
    width: '20%',
  },
```

Comment: Thank you :) It works!